# Kernel keeps dying when plotting a graph after importing the torch library

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import torch

x = y = torch.tensor([1,2,3]).numpy()
plt.plot(x,y);
```

I keep getting the message: `The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.` and a restart and a red "Dead kernel" tag on the toolbar.

But the weird thing is, if I import `matplotlib.pyplot` and plot some random graph first, the above code plots just fine. In other words, the following code works fine.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

plt.subplots(figsize=(0.01,0.01))
plt.gca().set_visible(False);

import torch
x = torch.tensor([1,2,3]).numpy()

plt.plot(x,x);
```

What is going on here? I'm using numpy 1.18.5, pytorch 1.6.0, matplotlib 3.2.2 on Python 3.7.7, if it matters. Thank you.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. If I comment out the import torch line, my code works fine and I get a nice image. But if I import torch before running a plt command, the kernel just dies

Comment: Did you manage to solve it on you own? If so, can you please post your solution? I wanted to ask something similar (and related) to your question, but my account is banned and I need some new ideas to solve my similar problem without asking on stackoverflow (I need to be upvoted to be able to do it...). Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
import os
os.environ["KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK"]="TRUE"
```

Run this first, then it'll resolve your problem. Although I guess, it is a temporary solution you can refer to this link: https://www.programmersought.com/article/53286415201/

Answer (score 0):

I followed the link above and deleted a couple of duplicate .dll's in Torch. Now everything runs fine

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31315145)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Anaconda environment for the Jupyter notebook, delete the libiomp5md.dll which is probably located in anaconda3\Library\bin. Already initalized dll is causing the kernel to die, so we have to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading NumPy with `pip install numpy --upgrade` does the trick for me. But the plotting becomes slow. To fast plotting, try to plot only after PyTorch trainings.